# custom grid filter doesn't work when filtering products by category (bl_customgride module)

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, product-grid, custom-admin-grid, custom-grid

I'm using BL_CustomGrid extension for customising admin grid, when I filter products grid by categories it throws me the error below, I couldn't find out how to diagnose the problem, if anyone has an idea I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

[image]

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:43:"Invalid attribute name: blcg_custom_field_1";i:1;s:7372:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1291): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid attribu...')
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_addAttributeJoin('blcg_custom_fie...', 'inner')
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql('blcg_custom_fie...', Array, 'inner')
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter('blcg_custom_fie...', Array, 'inner')
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->addAttributeToFilter('blcg_custom_fie...', Array)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on this post.
[Fixing Magento Invalid attribute name issue after SUPEE-11219](https://www.garybell.co.uk/fix-magento-invalid-attribute-error-supee-11219/)